# Excel VBA. How to select a certain cell, then offset a variable number or rows down, and then print that selection

Tags: vba, excel, variables, offset

Just like it says in the title. I need to print in an area from B18 to J18 and down a variable number of rows. I don't know how to set this up. That variable number is being kept in cell O24 by using a `=COUNTA(B20:B65536)`function. I just need the selection to go down that many number of rows.

Here is my code so far.

```
Sub PrintPlease()

I = Cells("O24").Value

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1

    ExecuteExcel4Macro ("PAGE.SETUP(,,,,,,,,,,,,{#N/A,#N/A})")
    If .Zoom < 30 Then
        .Zoom = 50
    Else
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End If

End With

Range ("B18:J18"), Cells("B18").Offset((I), 3).PrintOut, Preview:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("B18:J" & Range("O24").Value).PrintOut Preview:=True`. `Range("O24").Value` will return the value of cell O24 and then append it to the rest of the range, which begins at B18

Comment: That works! Put it in the answers section and ill mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Range("B18:J" & Range("O24").Value).PrintOut Preview:=True
```

Since the value in cell O24 contains the number of rows you want to print down to you can print the range beginning at cell B18 and ending at cell J and the value of cell O24 by appending the value in cell O24 to B18:J.